# What does "on his dignity with" mean in "The Case of the White Footprints"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, r-austin-freeman, dr-thorndyke

In "[The Case of the White Footprints](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks14/1402921h.html#c1)" in *Dr. Thorndyke's Case-Book* by R. Austin Freeman, a woman was talking to a detective about a situation in her hotel, saying:

> Mr. Bergson wasn't drunk, but he was excitable and noisy, and when I told him he mustn't come again he made such a disturbance that two of the gentlemen boarders—Mr. Wardale and Mr. Macauley—had to interfere. And then he was most insulting to them, especially to Mr. Macauley, who is a coloured gentleman; called him a "buck nigger" and all sorts of offensive names".
>
> "And how did the coloured gentleman take it?"
>
> "Not very well, I am sorry to say, considering that **he** is a gentleman—a law student with chambers in the Temple. In fact, **his** language was so objectionable that Mr. Wardale insisted on my giving **him** notice on the spot. But I managed to get him taken in next door but one; you see, Mr. Wardale had been a Commissioner at, Sierra Leone—it was through him that Mr. Toussaint got his appointment—so I suppose he was rather **on his dignity with coloured people**."

I think that **the bolded "he" refers to the coloured man**, but **the bolded "his & him" refer to "Mr. Bergson**"? As it is illogical that Mr. Wardale wanted her to dismiss the coloured man!! Is that right?!

And does "on his dignity with coloured people" mean "he think that **coloured people must be respected**" or "he **treated their dignity as if it was his own**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be on your dignity is to act in a very formal manner, [in order to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stand-on-your-dignity)

> to demand to be shown the respect that you think you deserve:

So, Mr. Wardale is being demanding because Mr. Macauley's language is so objectionable (despite the provocation) that it shows too much disrespect.  (Into the logic of that we shall not delve.)

As a Commissioner, being on his dignity was necessary to keep his work going, so he got into the habit and expects it even here.

Comment: Oh! I had really misunderstood it. So all "he, his and him" refer to the coloured man?!

Comment: Thank you so much, Mary